# How can I identify which architecture style a software project is adopting?

Tags: architecture

I came across this article introducing some styles of architecture:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/

Based on this , how can I identify which architecture style a software project is adopting ?

The project I am working on has many separate modules,
The modules send messages between each other ,
the message contains not only the command , but also the parameters needed for the commands.

The receiver parse the message strings ,parse the commands ,
and do corresponding job.

A module can play the role as a sender or a receiver.

What kind of architecture might be most likely it is using ?
Is the information provided above enough to determine its architecture style ?
If not ? What extra information are needed ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is a service invocation with asynchronous communication.
The modules are not tightly coupled. They are independent of each other since the modules send messages to interact with each other. Hence asynchronous.
Since the messages contain commands and all the parameters required to execute them, this is a mechanism to invoke a service/module.
To sum it up, this architecture is invoking modules/services asynchronously.
This is one of the best architecture style to invoke other services asynchronously instead of REST or gRPC which is synchronous.

Different types of messages can be sent:

- **Commands**:

1. Query - No changes to the data in the system it is interacting with.
2. Create/Update/Delete - Changes the data in the system through create/update.
   /delete

- **Notifications**:
  These are events sent to other modules indicating a state change